# Adding folder to GitHub shows up as binary file

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add a folder which contains other folders and files to my git repository. The steps I have taken are as follow:

1. Created a repo on GitHub.
2. CD'd into the directory I want the repo to be.
3. Cloned the repo.
4. Copied some files into the newly cloned repo on my local machine.
5. Used 'git add .' to add files and folders to GitHub.
6. Git commit -m "First commit"
7. Git push.

The result I am getting is that a folder called 'src' is being created in GitHub, but it is empty and states that it is a submodule.

On my local machine src contains two more folders (styles and php) and also a file (index.php).

I have tried different commands such as git add -A, git add --all, adding the force tag and so on, but with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show is the link to your github repo and do you have any .gitignore added to the project?

Comment: It's a private repository unfortunately, for a University project. There isn't a .gitignore, literally just the README.md and the submodule src. I can add individual files as normal, just it seems to fail with folders.

Comment: Actually this should'nt be a problem though...Have you copied some submodule directories maybe?

Comment: All I've done is cloned the repo onto my local machine, and the copied some files and folders into the folder created by cloning the repo, and then used the git add . command to add everything.

Comment: Yes and did you maybe copied some files from a different repo that might me a submodule so you maybe copied the meta files of that other repo.

Comment: Actually that might be the case, I believe I enabled VCS in phpstorm but didn't go any further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134072/discussion-between-ckruczek-and-alex).

Comment: Hey ckruczek, it turned out to be an issue with PhpStorm and it's .idea files, one wasn't removed by the command and couldn't be, so simply copying the individual files into a new folder solved the problem. So you were right in saying the .idea files could have been causing an issue, if you pop it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the chat it turned out that the `.idea` provided by PhpStorm is causing the problem. So to solve the issue you have to copy the individual files of your project but excluding the `.idea` file.